# i am facing error about apex images loading

Tags: apex

There is a problem with your environment because the Application Express files have not been loaded. Please verify that you have copied the images directory to your application server as instructed in the Installation Guide. In addition, please verify that your image prefix path is correct. Your current path is /i/ (it should contain both starting and ending forward slashes, such as the default /i/). Use the SQL script reset_image_prefix.sql if you need to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Apex 18.1.x.x.x we should be instead putting CDN location as static path for images. Local path will not be supported any further.
Take a look at below announcement :
https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/announcing-oracle-apex-static-resources-on-oracle-content-delivery-network

CDN makes application faster.

Coming to problem you mentioned, can be easily resolved by performing below steps :

1. Locate reset_image_prefix.sql . It should be under 'apex/utilities'
2. change directory :

   cd apex/utilities
3. Connect to DB and check what is image prefix

   connect to SQL as SYS
       SQL> set serveroutput on
       SQL> begin
         2  dbms_output.put_line(apex_200100.wwv_flow_image_prefix.g_image_prefix);
         3
         4  end;
         5  /

It should list /i/ or any other location you may have configured with
Note: whenever you run the above command change to the correct APEX user (version), so for APEX 19.1 you use apex_190100.
 4. Now, check CDN address. For example Apex 20.1.X.X.XX location is  - https://static.oracle.com/cdn/apex/20.1.0.00.13/
Same can be checked from https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/announcing-oracle-apex-static-resources-on-oracle-content-delivery-network
 5. Now, its time to run SQL (assuming you have APEX 19.2.0.X.XX version)

```
SQL> @reset_image_prefix.sql

Enter the Application Express image prefix [/i/] https://static.oracle.com/cdn/apex/19.2.0.00.18/
...Changing Application Express image prefix

NEW_IMAGE_PREFIX
------------------------------------------------
https://static.oracle.com/cdn/apex/19.2.0.00.18/
```

1. Go to http://your-host:your-port/ords/apex_admin

Problem should be resolved by now!